# Parameter sniffing - only in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

We develop an application that works with MS SQL Server - our customers run anything from SQL 2008 Express to 2017 Standard. Our queries are not parameterised and it is impractical to rewrite the whole application so that they are. We therefore have a lot of plans for the same query. I have seen that there is an option in SSMS against the database to set Parameterisation to Forced, so that there will be fewer query plans, but that this can then cause issues with Parameter Sniffing with Stored Procedures.

Before I try changing that option, can I just clarify that Stored Procedures are pieces of code that you explicitly create and store in the database; running queries directly from the application do NOT get turned into Stored Procedures (even temporarily), so it isn't a problem.

Comment: The real issue is right here "Our queries are not parameterised". It may not be practical to rewrite your application but how about when your system is vandalized through sql injection. And if you don't use parameters why are you even considering changing this option? You should spend your efforts fixing the application, you are going to be forced to at some point.

Comment: *"it is impractical to rewrite the whole application so that they are."* Impratical? Maybe. Foolish not to? Definitely. Start parametrising your queries, either using inline SQL or Stored Stored is "fine" (some prefer one option over the other) but regardless there queries need to be parametrised.

Comment: You don't really define a specific problem you are trying to correct - which is might be a big red flag. But perhaps this discussion of [optimizing ad-hoc workloads](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/) will help you understand what is happening and develop a plan (if needed)

Comment: @SMor - the problem as stated in the post is lots of query plans for the same query.

Comment: @Dondon841 And WHY is this a problem? You want to fiddle with parameters that can have significant impact - so what problem are you attempting to solve? The link I posted discusses plan cache management and highlights an important point about clearing single-use plan cache bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter sniffing can happen to both stored procedure calls and parameterized queries. In your case, the best option is to fix your application, which will take considerable efforts. So before that can happen, set the Parameterisation to Forced will certainly help to reduce the number of plans and tighten the security.

and no, this will not change your queries to stored procedures.